# How to add an dynamically a checkbox element on a Tabcontrol after Tabcontrol.Pages is from GUI Designer?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, tabcontrol, dynamically-generated

can i add tabcontrol elements after programm started?

i use a Tabcontrol from GUI-Designer and wanna manipulate a TabPage.
i want there new dynamical checkboxes on Formular _load.

i can't see these checkboxes on my TabPages

```
For i = 0 To frmMain.cmbZielSpache.Items.Count - 1

        Dim cBox = New CheckBox()
        cBox.Name = "GEN_" & i
        cBox.Location = New Point(offsetX, offsetY)
        cBox.Text = frmMain.cmbZielSpache.Items(i)

        If frmMain.cmbZielSpache.Items(i) = frmMain.cmbZielSpache.Text Or My.Settings.chkTranslate_normal_alleSprachen = True Then
            cBox.Checked = True
        End If

        offsetX = offsetX + 120

        Me.Controls.Add(cBox)
        AddHandler cBox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf checkChangedHandler

    Next i
```

Instead of using Me.Controls i wanna add the checkboxes after programm started dynamically.

Comment: Yes, you can. Not with `Me.Controls.Add(cBox)`, since you're adding the new Controls to a Form, not a TabPage. What shouldn't be there is `frmMain`. If you're using default instances, for some reason, I suggest you remove that reason first.

Comment: How to add a checkbox on a existing tabpage from GUI-Designer?

Comment: Instead of adding your controls to the `Me.Controls` collection, add them to the `[TabControl].TabPages(N).Controls` collection, where `[TabControl]` is your TabControl reference and `N` is the index of the TabPage that will host your CheckBoxes. I suggest you add a FlowLayoutPanel to the TabPage and add your CheckBoxes to the FlowLayoutPanel, so your code could be `[FlowLayoutPanel].Controls.Add(cBox)`

Comment: Thank you, really easy but i can't figure out hadn't thinked about Tabpage(0).Controlls.add()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is TabControl1.TabPages(0).Controls.add()

```
Sub checkChangedHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    lblSprachenListeZielSprachen.Text = "Ziel Übersetzungsprache: "
    For Each chkBox In TabControl1.TabPages(0).Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
        'Check here whether your check boxes are checked true/false
        If chkBox.Checked = True Then
            If Not chkBox.Name.IndexOf("GEN_") = -1 Then
                lblSprachenListeZielSprachen.Text &= chkBox.Text & ","
            End If
        End If
    Next
    gblAktiveÜbersetzungssprachen = lblSprachenListeZielSprachen.Text.Replace("Ziel Übersetzungsprache: ", "")
End Sub



 For i = 0 To frmMain.cmbZielSpache.Items.Count - 1

        Dim cBox = New CheckBox()
        cBox.Name = "GEN_" & i
        cBox.Location = New Point(offsetX, offsetY)
        cBox.Text = frmMain.cmbZielSpache.Items(i)

        If frmMain.cmbZielSpache.Items(i) = frmMain.cmbZielSpache.Text Or My.Settings.chkTranslate_normal_alleSprachen = True Then
            cBox.Checked = True
        End If

        offsetX = offsetX + 120

        AddHandler cBox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf checkChangedHandler

        Me.TabControl1.TabPages(0).Controls.Add(cBox)


    Next i
```